# How to get freshly added entities from repository?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I'm using a repository implementation which is using a shared `ObjectContext` with other repositories. The repository holds an `ObjectSet` of the entities. I'm adding new entities via `Add()` method to the `ObjectSet`. While importing data I would like to query those fresh added objects to prevent duplicate data.

The `ObjectContext` implements a unit of work pattern. At the end of the import process I would like to call the commit method which calls `context.SaveChange()` to persist the data.

However, I couldn't find an easy way to query the freshly added entities before I called `SaveChanges()`. How do you guys handle such problems?

Answer (score 6):

Query the `ObjectStateManager`.

```
var foo = context.ObjectStateManager
  .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
  .Select(s => s.Entity).OfType<Foo>().SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == bar);
```

Comment: The Problem is that the Context is not known inside the repository. The Context is injected via unity.  code public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
    {
        protected readonly IDbContext context;
        protected readonly IDbSet<T> entities;

        #region Constructor

        /// <summary>
        /// default constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">wrapped object context</param>
        public Repository(IDbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.entities = context.Set<T>();
        }´

Comment: @Flo Your abstraction(Repository) has let you down. Find a way to expose the full API of the Entity Framework.

Comment: I know this is late but for anyone facing the same issue, you can put a generic method inside `UnitOfWork` and use the context to get the latest added entry for any entity with the above mentioned implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I used **ObservableCollection** inside **repository.cs** to get the data before saving it to database as below

```
 public ObservableCollection<T> Local {
    get { return UnitOfWork.GetContext().Set<T>().Local; }
 }
```

if you want you can also use ICollection because it is a base class for observablecollection.

Now, you can query the repository as shown below...

```
 Repository.Local.Where(x=>x.TrackingNumber == order.TrackingNumber).SingleOrDefault();
```

But, remember you cannot get data using Id's before saving to database so use some other unique field to get data. For further info click on the below link where similar kind of question was asked by me

[Why I am not able to get recently added objects (yet to be saved in database) from repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037724/why-i-am-not-able-to-get-recently-added-objects-yet-to-be-saved-in-database-fr)